# inserting data into multiple postgres tables using a plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I need to insert data into multiple tables in postgres. I'm looking to minimize the number of requests from my nodejs postgres driver to the actual DB. I'm thinking of just creating a postgres function that takes JSON and stores the data in the appropriate tables (probably around 10 different tables). That way, I'd just have to call the function from node and postgres would do all the rest.

```
db.func('insertIntoDB', json)
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

So far it seems like a reasonable solution, I'm just wondering whether this is a good practice or not. Somebody once told me that everything within a postgres functions is within a transaction and that the operations are all highly optimized. Would this then be a good approach in terms of performance or are there better ways to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Check out some of the Pros duking it out - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/postgresql-stored-procedure-performance

Comment: according to that post, it seems like a good approach. Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the amount of data. If you need to insert just a single record into each of your tables, then it won't make a noticeable difference.